# MySql :: Stored procedure :: navicat

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, navicat

I have the following  stored procedure in MySql(navicat), but I need to test **RefrenceCount** 
after update operation, when I add if st. after the update statment. syntax error occurred

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_IncDecReferenceCount`(pReferenceID int,pIncValue int)
BEGIN
update filesrefrences
set 
    filesrefrences.RefrenceCount= filesrefrences.RefrenceCount+pIncValue 
where 
        filesrefrences.ReferenceID= pReferenceID;
IF Not EXISTS(SELECT * from filesrefrences where filesrefrences.ReferenceID= pReferenceID and filesrefrences.RefrenceCount>0) then 
DELETE from filesrefrences WHERE filesrefrences.ReferenceID = pReferenceID;
end if 
END

[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 11
```

Comment: Which error? Show error message.

Comment: code is avialabe now with msg error

Comment: I think you are missing ";" after `endif`.

Comment: yes ... it is solved ... thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
update filesrefrences
set 
    filesrefrences.RefrenceCount= filesrefrences.RefrenceCount+IF(pIncValue > 0,pIncValue,1)
where 
        filesrefrences.ReferenceID= pReferenceID;
```

OR

```
update filesrefrences
    set 
        filesrefrences.RefrenceCount= filesrefrences.RefrenceCount+pIncValue
    where 
            (filesrefrences.ReferenceID= pReferenceID) AND (pIncValue > 0);
```

Comment: sorry but I need to Delete the record if its reaches **0**